# Clearing textbox and adding to it - how to implement two modes?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I have such a code that generates random questions from some arrays (there can be many of them) into the textbox. Each question is asked by a certain button on the form and the result is copied to clipboard.

```
      private void buttonHi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        string[] Hi = new string[]
        {"How are you?", "What's up?", "How have you been?"};
        Random X = new Random();
        string Hi = Hi[X.Next(0, Hi.Length)];
        TextBox.Text = Hi;
        Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
       }

        private void buttonQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        string[] Question = new string[]
        {"Are you busy?", "What are you doing?", "Sleeping?"};
        Random X = new Random();
        string Hi = Question[X.Next(0, Question.Length)];
        TextBox.Text = Question;
        Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
       }
```

So I can greet a person or ask a question. When I ask a question aftree greeting a greeting from my textbox disappears. But what if I want to make longer phrases from the results of different buttons?

So that I get something like "Hi, how are you? What are you doing?"
 **Is there a way to add texts to a text box without deleting a previous text?
 And then copying an overall result to a clipboard.**

And at the same time having an old option of overwriting an old text with a new button press. I want to make such a switch in the form, but not sure how to do it.

P.S. I know that I can connect both arrays to one button and get combined results, but that's not what I need, cause I can have many more buttons and use them in different combinations.

Answer (score 1):

what about

```
TextBox.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", TextBox.Text, Question);
```

Then when you say `Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);` it copies all the text

EDIT:

If you want to replace the quesiton but keep the greeting then I suggest keeping a reference of the current question like this

```
private string _currentQuestion = String.Empty;
private void buttonHi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string[] Hi = new string[]
    {"How are you?", "What's up?", "How have you been?"};
    Random X = new Random();
    _currentQuestion = Hi[X.Next(0, Hi.Length)];
    TextBox.Text = _currentQuestion;
    Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
   }

    private void buttonQuestion_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    string[] Question = new string[]
    {"Are you busy?", "What are you doing?", "Sleeping?"};
    Random X = new Random();
    string Hi = Question[X.Next(0, Question.Length)];
    String.Format("{0} {1}", _currentQuestion, Question)
    Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I understand, this way a simple version when text is replaced won't work? I was just thinking to put a radio button or something to switch between two modes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it completely you want to add a question to a question in the same textbox?

Like:

```
TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text + " " + Question;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I understand, this way a simple version when text is replaced won't work? I was just thinking to put a radio button or something to switch between two modes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question consists of two parts. First:

> Is there a way to add texts to a text box without deleting a previous text?

Yes, just append the text, like this:

```
TextBox.Text += " " + Question;
```

Second:

> And then copying an overall result to a clipboard.

Sure. Set the `Clipboard`:

```
Clipboard.SetText(TextBox.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I understand, this way a simple version when text is replaced won't work? I was just thinking to put a radio button or something to switch between two modes.

Comment: That is possible too. Keep two variables for question and answer. On clicking the radio button, save the text to the appropriate variable and overwrite the value of the textbox with the other value. (You can do that using binding too, but that might be too complicated for now)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`AppendText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as following :

```
TextBox.AppendText("Hi");
```